# Newb Powershell question creating Adaptive Scope for Compliance

Tags: azure, powershell

I thought this would be pretty simple based on some examples I've read and followed...but Ps is hollering at me.  Any ideas what is wrong in this?  I'm doing this in a PS window not ISE.

```sh
$name = "SharePoint Teams AS1"
$comment = "PowerShell Adaptive Scope Multiple Advanced Filter"
$locationtype = "Site"

$filterconditions = @{
    "Conditions" = @(

            "Value" = "https://sitename"
            "Operator" = "Equals"
            "Name" = "SPSiteURL"
        },
        @{
            "Value" = "https://sitename"
            "Operator" = "Equals"
            "Name" = "SPSiteURL"
        }
        
    )
 "Conjunction" = "Or"
}
 
New-AdaptiveScope `
    -Name $name `
    -Comment $comment `
    -LocationType $locationtype `
    -FilterConditions $filterconditions
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is missing some brackets and curly boys.

```
$filterconditions = @{

'Conditions' = @(

@{
   'Value' = 'https://sitename'
   'Operator' = 'Equals'
   'Name' = 'SPSiteURL'
},

@{
   'Value' = 'https://sitename'
   'Operator' = 'Equals'
   'Name' = 'SPSiteURL'
 }
)
    'Conjunction' = 'Or'
}
```